# webpack inline-source-map is mapping to the wrong file

Tags: javascript, webpack, aem

I would prefer to use inline source maps in my webpack config as it sources to the actual original file.

my webpack config is...

```
const paths = {
  src: './widgets/src/scripts/index.js',
  dest: '/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/universal-template-abloyalty/clientlib/js'
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => { 
  return {
    devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    entry: paths.src,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + paths.dest,
      filename: 'widgets.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
  };
};
```

and then for example in my index.js i do a simple console log...

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

initReact = () => {
  function createRootElement() {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = 'root';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return el;
  }
  const root = document.getElementById('root') || createRootElement();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
  console.log('test');
};

if (typeof onReactReady === 'function') onReactReady();
```

The problem I am having is that in my browser console, this should obviously map to `index.js:16` using inline-source-map. Instead its mapping to `MobileFilterComponent.js:15`

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Interestingly enough when I use `eval-source-map` it maps correctly, but with an altered file name. This makes looking up a file from ctrl+p in sources a pain as you may not know how the file is named.

**note I tagged this with AEM, as this is for an AEM project. I am wondering if maybe when AEM builds clientlib.js if some how the source maps are getting corrupted.

Comment: Are you using the standard AEM clientlib minification?

Comment: @ronnyfm yes we are. I think this is why the mapping is getting mixed up actually.

Comment: Try disabling it and see if it works without AEM minification, and either consider to minify using Webpack as well.